# PictureMarkerSymbol in iOS Xamarin does not load an image from the local file system or included in the MainBundle

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, arcgis

We have an iOS app using the 100.2.1 sdk.

We need to load an image from the MainBundle or file system to dynamically change the image to load depending on the user.

We are attempting with this code:

```
    var url = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("StreetsIconSmall", "png", "Images");
    if (url == null || url.Length == 0)
       return null;

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(url))
       return null;

    return new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.PictureMarkerSymbol(new Uri(url));
```

The file exists and it was compiled with buildaction "BundleResource"

This same code works just fine, if we put the same image on our server and use a web url such as http://domain/images/StreetsIconSmall.png.

Also, the image works when loaded to a UIImageView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a `NSUrl`, you can use the `GetUrlForResource` method directly.

```
var url = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("StreetsIconSmall", "png", "Images");
```

iOS contains a **case sensitive** file system, so in the example above, the `StreetsIconSmall.png` needs to be in an sub-directory named "Images" (i.e. the capital `I`) otherwise that method will return `null`.

```
├── Resources
│   ├── Images
│   │   └── StreetsIconSmall.png
```

Note: And of course it needs to be flagged with a build action of `BundleResource`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue here is not obtaining the url. Is that PictureMarkerSymbol cannot load the image when it is local. If I were to load that url into a UIImage it works.

But thank you!

Comment: @OscarAzmitia Sorry, mis-read your question, you can create a `RuntimeImage` and use that as a param in the PictureMarkerSymbol .ctor, you can also create a PictureMarkerSymbol from an embedded assemby resource....